# using java commands to load data with SQL Screwdriver

Tags: java, r

I'm following a set of instructions in order to load data to an h2 database to which later connect using R. the first step is to load data using Java at the command line. There are concrete instructions on which commmands to use. For example:

```
java -classpath SQLScrewdriver.jar:h2-1.3.170.jar \
com.winvector.db.LoadFiles \
file:dbDef.xml \
```

Where do I execute these commands?  Should I use a concrete CLI? I'm a newbie using all these tools and I'm kind of lost. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You type those commands into a Terminal window (on Mac), or a shell prompt (on Linux/Unix) or a command prompt window (on Windows).

From the commands you write, you'll want the terminal window to be in the directory where the SQLScrewdriver.jar and h2-1.3.170.jar files are located (and where the dbDef.xml file is also...otherwise you'll need to add the directory location to the file name, so that these can be found by the program).  On Mac (or basically any Unix/Linux machine) you'll want to first type 'cd /path/to/the/jar/files' into the terminal window first, so that you end up where the jar files are located.

You may want to spend an hour or 2 with a basic Java tutorial so that you get comfortable running java programs. Good luck.  BTW, I think 'Practical Data Science with R' is a good book.